# Save TensorFlow model for Tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I trained a chatbot in TensorFlow and would like to save the model in order to deploy it with TensorFlow.js to web. I have the following

```
checkpoint = "./chatbot_weights.ckpt"
session = tf.InteractiveSession()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(session, checkpoint)


# Converting the questions from strings to lists of encoding integers
def convert_string2int(question, word2int):
    question = clean_text(question)
    return [word2int.get(word, word2int['<OUT>']) for word in question.split()]

# Setting up the chat
while(True):
    question = input("You: ")
    if question == 'Goodbye':
        break
    question = convert_string2int(question, questionswords2int)
    question = question + [questionswords2int['<PAD>']] * (25 - len(question))
    fake_batch = np.zeros((batch_size, 25))
    fake_batch[0] = question
    predicted_answer = session.run(test_predictions, {inputs: fake_batch, keep_prob: 0.5})[0]
    answer = ''
    for i in np.argmax(predicted_answer, 1):
        if answersints2word[i] == 'i':
            token = ' I'
        elif answersints2word[i] == '<EOS>':
            token = '.'
        elif answersints2word[i] == '<OUT>':
            token = 'out'
        else:
            token = ' ' + answersints2word[i]
        answer += token
        if token == '.':
            break
    print('ChatBot: ' + answer)
```

and it gives the following files (and I can test the bot in the console):

[image: saved files]

But in the documentation it says I should use SaveModel or Frozen, can anyone help here? I'm not sure how to implement. Thanks.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md

Answer (score 1):

To deploy your model in the browser, you first need to convert it using [tfjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter). You can have a look at the following [tutorial](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-saved-model.html) to see how to proceed.

For the model to be successfully converted, all the ops used in your model should be already supported in the browser. Here is the full [list](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/blob/master/docs/supported_ops.md) of the ops that are currently supported.

Once your model is converted and that you have the files of the model and the weight, you can load it using [loadFrozenModel](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.5/#loadFrozenModel):

```js
const model = await loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
...
model.execute({input: the_input_of_the_model});
```